# How to force to use jQuery 1.9.x with bootstrap 3.1 with rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering why my application didn't work anymore, it's because I imported inside my `Gemfile` these depencencies:

`# Use rails-assets. See https://rails-assets.org/.
gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'
gem 'rails-assets-jquery.browser'`

If I take a look about these gems, I can see that they both load this via `require "rails-assets-jquery"`

*rails-assets-jquery-2.1.0/lib/rails-assets-jquery.version.rb*:

`module RailsAssetsJquery
  VERSION = "2.1.0"
end`

I don't want to use 2.1, because it doesn't support IE8 anymore, I need 1.9.x, but how can I force to use this version?

**More explanations**
I'm actually working on the new version of the application, migrating from bootstrap 2.3 to 3.1, I need to upgrade jquery from 1.7 to 1.9 (bootstrap 3 requirement). But I need to run both applications at the same time, because some parts of the application still use the old version. I need to make my code works with both.

My first issue is that if I import bootstrap in my Gemfile, I automatically use 2.1 in both version and the old code is broken with `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'`.

i'm not sure if what I want to do is possible, maybe I should not use gems to use bootstrap 3.x...

Comment: Did you try to define version of jquery in your gemfile? Something like `gem 'rails-assets-jquery', '1.9.1'`

Comment: I use the gem `gem 'jquery-rails'` and no, I don't force the version, I'll try.

Comment: I ran 'bundle update jquery-rails' and got `Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 1.9.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.`, same with the `rails-assets-jquery` gem, and I don't know how find the repository. I searched there: `https://rails-assets.org/components` but couldn't find the repo or a way to force the jQuery version used.

Comment: jquery-rails versions compared to jQuery: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md jquery-rails has never bundled jQuery 2, so probably the problem is in rails-assets-jquery. Anyway, I think you should choose one of them, instead of using both

Comment: Pay attention with using `jquery-rails` and `rails-assets-jquery-XXX` next to each others. We just ran into a problem, where we thought `jquery-rails` was providing our `jquery 1.11.X`. BUT: `rails-assets-jquery.cookie` requires ` rails-assets-jquery` which ships 2.1.4!